# Closure operation is not necessarily preserved

Tags: metric-spaces

> If $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ are metric spaces and if $f:X\rightarrow Y$, 
>   show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for every $A\subset X$,
>   $f(\overline{A})\subset\overline{f(A)}$, and construct an example to show that the closure operation is not necessarily preserved by a continuous mapping. Moreover, if $f$ is a $1:1$ onto, show that $X$ and $Y$ are 
>   homeomorphic is and only if  $f(\overline{A})=\overline{f(A)}$ for all 
>   $A\subset X$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose first that $f$ is continuous and let $x\in\overline{A}$, which 
>            means that for any open set $f(x)\in O\subset Y$ we have $f^{-1}(O)\cap 
>          A\ne\varnothing$ because $x\in f^{-1}(O)$ and $f^{-1}(O)$ is open, but 
>            $f^{-1}(O)\cap A\ne\varnothing\Rightarrow O\cap f(A)\ne\varnothing$ indeed
>            if $O\cap f(A)=\varnothing$ then 
>            $$\varnothing=f^{-1}(O\cap f(A))=f^{-1}(O)\cap f^{-1}(f(A))\supset 
>          f^{-1}(O)\cap A$$
>            which is a contradiction with our initial assumption, so
>            $O\cap f(A)\ne\varnothing$ for any open $O$ containing $f(x)$ so 
>            $f(x)\in\overline{f(A)}\Rightarrow f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$.
>            Now suppose that for any $A\in X$, $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$,
>            Let $U=f^{-1}(O)\in X$ where $O$ is arbitrary open set of $Y$ we claim that
>            $U$ is open. But for this note that $x\in \overline{U^{c}}
>          \Rightarrow x \notin U$, indeed if $x\in U$ when we note that 
>            \begin{eqnarray*}
>             &&f(U^{c})=f(X)\cap O^{c}\\
>             &&f(\overline{U^{c}})\subset\overline{f(U^{c})}=\overline{ 
>             f(X)\cap O^{c}}\subset\overline{f(X)}\cap\overline{O^{c}}=
>             \overline{f(X)}\cap O^{c}
>          \end{eqnarray*}
>            which is certainly a contradiction, because $f(x)\in f(\overline{U^{c}})$
>            but as we assume that $x\in U\Rightarrow x\notin U^{c}\Rightarrow
>          f(x)\notin O^{c}$. So for every open $O$ $f^{-1}(O)$ is open and so $f$ is 
>            continuous. Now define,
>            \begin{eqnarray*}
>             f : \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}\\
>             x &\mapsto & e^{x}
>          \end{eqnarray*}
>            with the usual metric $f(\mathbb{R})=(0,\infty)$ which is not closed. Nos
>            suppose that $f$ is one-to-one and that $f(\overline{A})=\overline{ 
>          f(A)}$ for all $A\subset X$ then by what we have just proven $f$ is 
>            continuous, furthermore as $f$ is one-to-one we can rewrite 
>            $\overline{A}=f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ now call $B=f(A)$ and recall that 
>            $f$ is a one-to-one map onto $Y$ so 
>            $$\overline{f^{-1}(B)}=f^{-1}(\overline{B})$$
>            and so $f^{-1}$ is continuous too, and so $f$ is a homeomorphism.
>            Conversely let $f$ be a homeomorphism. The as $A\subset\overline{A}
>          \Rightarrow f(A)\subset f(\overline{A})$ recall that $f$ is a homeomorphism
>            so $f(\overline{A})$ is closed and so $f(A)\subset f(\overline{A})
>          \Rightarrow \overline{f(A)}\subset\overline{f(\overline{A})}=
>          f(\overline{A})$, now let $y=f(x)\notin \overline{f(A)}$ then for some 
>            $\varepsilon>0$, $S_{\varepsilon}(y)\cap f(A)=\varnothing 
>          \Rightarrow f^{-1}(S_{\varepsilon}(y))\cap A=\varnothing \Rightarrow 
>          f^{-1}(y)\notin\overline{A}\Rightarrow y\notin f(\overline{A})$ so we 
>            have just proven that 
>            \begin{eqnarray*}
>             \overline{f(A)}^{c}\subset f(\overline{A})^{c}\Rightarrow 
>             \overline{f(A)}\supset f(\overline{A})
>          \end{eqnarray*}
>            then $f(\overline{A})=\overline{f(A)}$, which finishes the solution.